# Matlab code for rolling disk without slipping in 3-D

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need Matlab code for disk rolling without slipping in 3-D. and in 2-D.
I have tried this code for 2-D, but it doesn't work.

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
figure;
%XX=[0 2 4 5 0];
%YY=[1 0 1 5 1];
NN=100;
RR=3;
th=linspace(-2*pi,8*pi);
XX=RR*cos(th);
YY=RR*sin(th);
% XXa=XX+sin(th(1,:))*RR;
%     YYa=RR-cos(th(1,:))*RR; 

h=patch('XData',XX,'YData',YY,'FaceColor',[0.5, 0.8, 0.7]);
pointA = line('xdata', XX(1), 'ydata', YY(1), 'marker', 'o', 'color', 'r', 'markerfacecolor', 'b', 'linewidth', 0.5);
axis([-3 40 -3 38]);
axis square
d=5;
dX=d/length(th);
for ii=1:length(th)
    XX=XX+dX;
    XXa=XX+XX;

    YYa=RR+YY;

    set(h,'XData',XX);
    set(pointA, 'Xdata', XXa, 'Ydata', YYa);
    drawnow;
    pause(0.05)
end
```

Comment: What does "slipping" mean in this context?  Please clarify as someone who is not familiar with this vocabulary or this field would not know what you're talking about.  Also, why does this code not work?

Comment: Please be specific about "doesn't work". Also, this site is not a code-writing service. We can answer specific questions rather than solving broad problems like the one you describe. Please [read the FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @rayryeng: rolling without slip is a kinematic constraint equivalent to saying the velocity of the wheel center is equal to the rotational speed times the wheel radius. In 2-D think of the wheel as a gear rolling on a rack.

Comment: @horchler Thank you very much. I have no knowledge in this area so it's nice to be given a good intuitive explanation.